# Trying to code a rock paper scissors game in Javascript but keep returning one statement

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I've changed around my code a bunch, but here is the current simple version:

```
hands = ["rock","paper", "scissors"];
computerSelection = hands[Math.floor(Math.random() * hands.length)];
console.log(computerSelection)
playerSelection = prompt("Do you want to choose rock, paper, or scissors?").toLowerCase();
console.log(playerSelection);


function Result (playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
        gameResult = "Tie";    
    } if ((computerSelection == "paper" && playerSelection == "rock") || (computerSelection == "scissors" && playerSelection == "paper") || (computerSelection == "rock" && playerSelection == "scissors")) {
        gameResult = "Computer wins";
    }
    if ((computerSelection == "scissors" && playerSelection == "rock") || (computerSelection == "paper" && playerSelection == "scissors") ||(computerSelection == "rock" && playerSelection == "paper")) {
        gameResult = "You win";
        }
    else {
        gameResult = "Please enter a valid prompt";
    }
console.log(gameResult);
}

Result ()
```

The code at first always gave out a "tie" result and now always just spits out "please enter a valid prompt". I originally had computerselection as a function and changed that around. I'm not very used to Javascript, more to  python, so there might be issues with formatting?

Comment: you need to pass `Result(playerSelection , computerSelection )` in your function call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the variables into your function for them to be read in the function scope.

`Result(playerSelection, computerSelection);`

You can also improve your code by returning a string from the Result function so that it can be used in futher sections of code.

```js
const hands = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
const computerSelection = hands[Math.floor(Math.random() * hands.length)];
const playerSelection = prompt(
  "Do you want to choose rock, paper, or scissors?", ''
).toLowerCase();

console.log('Computer Selection: ' + computerSelection);
console.log('Player Selection: ' + playerSelection);

function Result(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
    return "Tie";
  }

  if (
    (computerSelection == "paper" && playerSelection == "rock") ||
    (computerSelection == "scissors" && playerSelection == "paper") ||
    (computerSelection == "rock" && playerSelection == "scissors")
  ) {
    return "Computer wins";
  }

  if (
    (computerSelection == "scissors" && playerSelection == "rock") ||
    (computerSelection == "paper" && playerSelection == "scissors") ||
    (computerSelection == "rock" && playerSelection == "paper")
  ) {
    return "You win";
  }

   return "Please enter a valid prompt";
}

const gameResult = Result(playerSelection, computerSelection);

console.log(gameResult);
```

Comment: It's such a simple thing that I've missed, I've been going insane over this haha

Comment: @boringbio no problem, even experienced devs make simple mistakes! Don't forget to mark the response as the correct answer!